# Find all $n$ so that $c_n$ $>$ $\pi(n^2)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

> Find all $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ so that $p_{c_n}$ $>$ $n^2$ where $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime and $c_n$, the  $n$-th composite.

I have tried doing the problem using The stronger version of Roger's Theorem, i.e., by the inequality, $$\ln n + \ln \ln n > \dfrac {p_n}{n} > \ln n + \ln \ln n - 1$$ but in vain.

I think that the problem is true for all sufficiently large values of $n$. Even a proof of *only* this claim will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From equation $(6)$ of [this MathSciNet page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html) we have

$$
\pi(n) > \frac{n}{\log n}
$$

for $n \geq 17$, so for $n \geq 5$ we have

$$
\pi(n^2) > \frac{n^2}{2\log n}.
$$

Also,

$$
c_n \leq 2n+2
$$

for all $n \geq 1$.

Since $n^2/(2\log n)$ is increasing for $n > \sqrt{e}$ and strictly convex and

$$
2n+2 |_{n=11} < \left.\frac{n^2}{2\log n}\right|_{n=11},
$$

we know that

$$
2n+2 < \frac{n^2}{2\log n}
$$

and hence that

$$
c_n < \pi(n^2)
$$

for $n \geq 11$.  Thus the largest value of $n$ satisfying $c_n > \pi(n^2)$ must be less than or equal to $10$, and one can check by hand that it is $n = 6$.